# Way to add checked and changed properties for the selected row in a table using check box

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time to develop a react application. 
It seems that I encounter error when adding functions in checked and changed properties in the check box, as well as check all rows in the table.

It seems that there is no class to create a constructor and states in this sample.

Thank you for your help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useTableState } from "react-table";
import { Button } from "../Styles";
import Table from "../TransactionPanelTable";

// Simulate a server
const getServerData = async ({ filters, sortBy, pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
  const filtersArr = Object.entries(filters);
  let rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    rows.push({
      transaction_seq: 1234,
      rec_count: 1234,
      user_id: "test",
      updated_at: "",
      duration: 1.23
    });
  }

  // Apply Filters
  if (filtersArr.length) {
    rows = rows.filter(row =>
      filtersArr.every(([key, value]) => row[key].includes(value))
    );
  }

  // Apply Sorting
  if (sortBy.length) {
    const [{ id, desc }] = sortBy;
    rows = [...rows].sort(
      (a, b) => (a[id] > b[id] ? 1 : a[id] === b[id] ? 0 : -1) * (desc ? -1 : 1)
    );
  }

  // Get page counts
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(rows.length / pageSize);
  const rowStart = pageSize * pageIndex;
  const rowEnd = rowStart + pageSize;

  // Get the current page
  rows = rows.slice(rowStart, rowEnd);

  return {
    rows,
    pageCount
  };
};

const columns = [
  {
    Header: "Rejected Transaction(s)",
    className: "left",
    columns: [
      {
        **id: "checkbox",
        accessor: "",
        Cell: ({ original }) => {
          return (
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="checkbox"
              checked={() => }
             onChange={() => test()}
            />
          );
        },
        Header: x => {
          return (
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="checkbox"
              //checked={this.state.selectAll === 1}
              //ref={input => {
              //if (input) {
              //input.indeterminate = this.state.selectAll === 2;
              //  }
              //}}
              //onChange={() => this.toggleSelectAll()}
            />
          );**
        },
        sortable: false,
        width: 45
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to track each individual checked row and store it in the state.

```
let checkedMap = new Map()
rows.forEach(row => checkedMap.set(row, false)) //preset each to false, ideally w/ a key instead of the entire row
this.setState({checkedMap: checkedMap})
```

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  className="checkbox"
  checked={this.state.checkedMap.get(original)} //again, use a key
  onChange={() => handleCheckedChange(original)}
/>
```

```
handleCheckedChange(row) {
  let modifiedMap = this.state.checkedMap
  modifiedMap.set(row, !this.state.checkedMap.get(row))
  this.setState({checkedMap: modifiedMap})
}
```

ETA: For hooks:

```
const [checkedMap, setCheckedMap] = useState(new Map())
let newMap = new Map()
rows.forEach(row => newMap.set(row, false)) //preset each to false, ideally w/ a key instead of the entire row
setCheckedMap(newMap)
```

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  className="checkbox"
  checked={checkedMap.get(original)} //again, use a key
  onChange={() => handleCheckedChange(original)}
/>
```

```
const handleCheckedChange = row => {
  let modifiedMap = checkedMap
  modifiedMap.set(row, !checkedMap.get(row))
  setCheckedMap(modifiedMap)
}
```

Comment: Hi jake, I encounter error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined when I add this.setState({checkedMap: checkedMap})

Comment: I added the way to do it for hooks, which you'll have to use `useState` instead

Comment: Thank you for your help Jake, the code is working, but seems this, modifiedMap and row is undefined when I add breakpoint in handleCheckedChange method. Original is also undefined.